# Why would removing gnash also remove gnome-desktop-enviroment?

Tags: gnome, flash, dependencies

I've been having flash troubles with my firefox.  someone from some place suggested trying gnash.  It worked for a while but while it re-enabled flash player on youtube, it is still incompatible with other flash apps out there.

when i tried to remove it, it says it will also remove gnome-desktop-environment.  why?  why should removing gnash, a mere flash plugin, remove my desktop environment?

Answer (score 2):

gnome-desktop-environment depends on swfdec-gnome, which in turn depends on gnash.

Fortunately gnome-desktop-environment is a metapackage (e.g. it doesn't install any files); removing it shouldn't cause problems.

Comment: it actually did.  not the gnash one, but when I was removing all flash related software before i installed gnash, it actually removed my entire gnome desktop.  i reinstalled the gnome desktop back through TTY.  When I decided to remove gnash, I noticed that it also wanted to remove something gnome-desktop related.  so removing flash somehow will remove the gnome-desktop.  It's not a comfortable thought.

Comment: gnome-desktop-environment isn't included in a default ubuntu install, so removing it definitely shouldn't be a problem. The default metapackage is ubuntu-desktop, which doesn't depend on gnash.

Comment: I'm not sure how you removed gnash, but there is no way it should remove GNOME with it.  Somehow you must have done more than just uninstalling gnash.  It would be very useful for us to know exactly what you did...

Comment: What I mean: how did you install Ubuntu, how did you install GNOME, are you using any third party utilities to manage the OS, ...?  It could all be useful info...

Comment: the desktop was removed when i tried to remove flash related files with the default flushplugin-installer, ubuntu-restricted-extras, and that removed something, i can't reproduce now, and when i restarted, i can get into the GDM, but the desktop itself was gone.  I can not get any further than GDM.  The way I resolved it was reinstalling gnome-desktop through TTY.